# Kubernetes Lens logs messed up with tqdm

Tags: kubernetes, tqdm

When looking at the log of a pod in K8S Lens it seems that `tqdm` messes up the log to the point of making it completely unreadable. If I do `kubectl logs <pod-name>` there is no issue, also in the Terminal of Lens.

I noticed that in the log window for the pod, I can hover my mouse over the lines and see the "actual" log lines, but not when just looking at it, see image below (note the line highlighted in gray saying `date hour latest_price ...` which is visible due to mouse hovering.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: I noticed that if I include timestamps in the log (option from Lens), then everything looks fine. This isn't the answer to my question, but it is at least a usable work-around:

[image]